# Spring boot REST application

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I am trying to make a RESTful application in Java using Spring boot by following the tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/). I want to modify it so that I can extract an identifier from the URL and use it to serve requests.

So `http://localhost:8080/members/<memberId>` should serve me a JSON object with information about the member whose ID is `<memberId>`. I don't know how to

1. Map all http://localhost:8080/members/* to a single controller.
2. Extract the  from the URL.
3. Should the logic of extracting the memberId and using it be part of the controller or a separate class, as per the MVC architecture?

I am new to Spring/Spring-boot/MVC. It is quite confusing to get started with. So please bear with my newbie questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the code below, service for customer are in one controller to get one and to add new customer.

So, you will have 2 services:

http://localhost:8080/customer/

http://localhost:8080/customer/{id}

```
@RestController("customer")
public class SampleController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Customer greetings(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName("Eddu");
    customer.setLastname("Melendez");
    return customer;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void add(@RequestBody Customer customer) {

}

class Customer implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> Map all http://localhost:8080/members/* to a single controller.

You can use a placeholder in a request mapping to so it'll handle multiple URLs. For example:

```
@RequestMapping("/members/{id}")
```

> Extract the id from the URL

You can have the value of a placeholder injected into your controller method using the `@PathVariable` annotation with a value that matches the name of the placeholder, "id" in this case:

```
@RequestMapping("/members/{id}")
public Member getMember(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    // Look up and return the member with the matching id       
}
```

> Should the logic of extracting the memberId and using it be part of the controller or a separate class, as per the MVC architecture?

You should let Spring MVC extract the member id from the URL as shown above. As for using it, you'll probably pass the URL to some sort of repository or service class that offers a `findById` method.